# What is the most important parts of the video card in Bitcoin mining?

Tags: mining-hardware, hashpower, gpu-mining, memory

For example, obviously it doesn't matter what type of adapters a video card offers when it comes to Bitcoin mining? Is the GPU speed or the amount of RAM the most important part in terms of megahashes per second?

Comment: Number of cores > Clock speed > Instruction set that's good for SHA256 > Latency to CPU. Memory basically doesn't matter.

Comment: @NickODell so number of cores or number of GPUs a video card has is the most important?

Comment: @NickODell: I mean, it's not terribly relevant today, but do you remember why this was closed as "too localized"?

Comment: @Murch Don't recall. General disdain towards mining questions?

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 does not require much, but if you intend to use it for scrypt mining too, it's said that memory is most important, i.e. speed and size.

Comment: So scrypt mining is fore litecoin right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU speed when hashing SHA256 is the most important requirement. A good graphics card for mining this are usually ATI brand cards as these work by using a massive array of parallel shaders.

Nvidia cards generally perform with a higher floating point performance but achieve this via different means which dont perform as well against SHA256

Other hash types such as scrypt that Litecoin uses has some requirement for memory also, native clock speed is generally the defining factor on performance though.

Comment: What about the new Titans by Nvidia? Since they have more CUDAs does that mean they are better fit for bitcoin mining?

Comment: By first glance technically speaking it should perform as well as a 7970 for mining but OpenCL seems better optimized than CUDA for mining process, its hard to tell on paper we need a benchmark review.